# Can't get data from database for my login page :(

Tags: php, html, database, phpmyadmin

I'm trying to get data from the database for my login page, but can't seem to do so. It keeps on telling me that my username or password is wrong.

I'm a beginner in this field and got my codes from youtube.

form1.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Login Site</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="POST" action="connect2.php">
Username : <input type="text" name="username"><br><br>
Password : <input type="password" name="password"><br>
<input type="submit" value="Login" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

connect2.php

```
<?php
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "") or die("Failed to connect to MySQL."); 
mysqli_select_db($con, "abc") or die("Database does not exist."); 
//require ('sql_connect.php');
if (isset($_POST['submit'])){
    $username=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['username']);
    $password=mysqli_escape_string($_POST['password']);
    if (!$_POST['username'] | !$_POST['password']) {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('You did not complete all of the required fields')
            window.location.href='form1.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
        exit();
    }
    $sql= mysqli_query("SELECT * 
                        FROM `account` 
                        WHERE username = $username 
                        AND password = $password ");
    if(mysqli_num_rows($sql) > 0) {
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Login Succesfully!.')
            window.location.href='form1.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
        exit();
    }else{
        echo ("<SCRIPT LANGUAGE='JavaScript'>
            window.alert('Wrong username or password. Please re-enter.')
            window.location.href='form1.html'
        </SCRIPT>");
        exit();
    }
}else{
}
?>
```

I think there is something wrong with the PHP coding since I keep on getting the 'wrong username and password' message.

UPDATE: screenshot of my database https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWXc9.jpg

Comment: use  `logical OR operator(||)` insted of `|`

Comment: Your script is open to [SQL Injection Attack](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php) attack. 
Even [if you are escaping inputs, its not safe!](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5741187/sql-injection-that-gets-around-mysql-real-escape-string)
You should consider using [prepared parameterized statements](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) in either the `MYSQLI_` or `PDO` API's instead of concatenated values

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: Plain text passwords are a very bad idea: PHP provides [`password_hash()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)
and [`password_verify()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.password-verify.php) please use them for the safety of your users.

Answer (score 2):

As quick fix, put quotes around the username and password variables :

```
SELECT * FROM `account` WHERE username = '$username' AND password = '$password'
```

Some tips to improve this code :

- use prepared statements to avoid SQL injections
- don't store password in plain text, hash it (with a salt)

Also, you have an error in your first condition, you use `|` which is a bitwise operator, instead of `||` which is the logical OR operator

Comment: Also, should use PHP `header` to redirect instead of javascript

Comment: I'm still a beginner in this field and, i haven't learned about hashing password with a salt.

Comment: I've tried putting quotes around the variables, it still doesn't work...

Comment: Joffrey It is better to suggest using `password_hash()` and `password_verify()` and letting that create a very good salt internally, rather than simply suggesting to hash with a salt.

Answer (score -2):

I think

`"SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = $username AND password = $password "`

should be

`"SELECT * FROM account WHERE username = \"$username\" AND password =\"$password\""`